# Great accuracy on IMDB Sentiment Analysis. Is there any train data leakage I'm missing?

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, confusion-matrix

I'm getting an unusual high accuracy on a sentiment analysis classifier I'm testing with python `sklearn` library. This is usually some sort of training data leakage but I can't figure out if that's the case.

My dataset has ~50k nonduplicated IMDB reviews.

```
import pandas as pd
import sklearn
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfVectorizer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import TfidfTransformer
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer
from sklearn.linear_model import SGDClassifier
from sklearn.model_selection import GridSearchCV
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline
from pprint import pprint
from time import time
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report,confusion_matrix,accuracy_score, roc_curve, auc, plot_confusion_matrix
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(imdb_data.text, imdb_data.label, test_size=0.30, random_state=2)

imdb_data=pd.read_csv('../../data/home/data/tm/en-sentiment/imdb_reviews_train.csv')
imdb_data=imdb_data.drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True)
imdb_data['label'] = imdb_data.label.map(lambda x: int(1) if x =='pos' else int(0) if x =='neg' else np.nan)

x_train, x_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(imdb_data.text, imdb_data.label, test_size=0.30, random_state=2)

pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('vect', CountVectorizer()),
    ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
    ('clf', SGDClassifier()),
])

parameters_final = {
    'vect__max_df': [0.3],
    'vect__min_df': [1],
    'vect__max_features': [None],
    'vect__ngram_range': [(1, 2)], 
    'tfidf__use_idf': (True, False),
    'tfidf__norm': ['l2'],
    'tfidf__sublinear_tf': (True, False),
    'clf__alpha': (0.00001, 0.000001),
    'clf__penalty': ['elasticnet'],
    'clf__max_iter': [50],
}

grid_search = GridSearchCV(pipeline, parameters_final, n_jobs=-1, verbose=1, cv=3)
grid_search.fit(x_train, y_train)
y_pred = grid_search.predict(x_test)
print("Accuracy: ", sklearn.metrics.accuracy_score(y_true=y_test, y_pred=y_pred))
```

Output:

```
Accuracy:  0.8967533466687183
```

The review dataset can be found [here](https://github.com/ricardorei/lightning-text-classification/blob/master/data/imdb_reviews_train.csv)

Any clues?

Comment: Looks alright. You may compare against https://paperswithcode.com/sota/sentiment-analysis-on-imdb or https://www.kaggle.com/nilanml/imdb-review-deep-model-94-89-accuracy

Comment: Thanks for the links. I'm using a basic SGDClassifier with no text pre-processing (was just getting started). Yet its till seems too high

Comment: Just ran again with different hyperparams and got `Accuracy:  0.9110771581359817`. Something must be off!

Comment: Would be interesting to see params giving .91 on this dataset

Comment: @SergeyBushmanov `clf__alpha: 1e-05
 clf__max_iter: 50
 clf__penalty: 'elasticnet’
 clf__loss: ‘hinge’
 tfidf__norm: 'l2'
 tfidf__sublinear_tf: True
 tfidf__use_idf: True
 vect__max_df: 0.3
 vect__max_features: None
 vect__min_df: 1
 vect__ngram_range: (1, 2)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A good way to test if there is data leakage would be to check the performance on the validation set in the repository you linked, [here](https://github.com/ricardorei/lightning-text-classification/blob/master/data/imdb_reviews_test.csv).

I downloaded the dataset and tried to construct a Naive Bayes classifier with a pipeline like so:

```
pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('vect', CountVectorizer()),
    ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
    ('clf', MultinomialNB()),
])
```

Using the same train–test split as you, I got an accuracy score of 0.86 on the hold-out data from the training set, and 0.83 on the validation set. If you get similar results, I think it might just be the case that the dataset isn't too difficult to learn from. I checked to see if there were any `NA` values that might be causing the strange performance, but `imdb_data.isnull().any()` does indeed return false.

Comment: I have been working with this dataset and apparently we can effectively get good accuracies with less sophisticated feature vectorization and classifiers.